# Pick a row with a specific index in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I want to output all image files of a specific productid. What is the right syntax to output the image path for row 1, row 2, row 3 etc? I can not find it.

```
            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM images
                    WHERE productid = $productid"; 

            $select = $db->prepare($sql);
            $select->execute(array());      


        foreach($select as $index => $rs) {

        if($rs['imagepath']){
             if($index == 0){
               echo $imagepath[0];  // <---What is the right sytax of this?
           }
        }

       if($rs['imagepath']){
            if($index == 1){
                echo $imagepath[1]; // <---and this?
           }
       }

      if($rs['imagepath']){
            if($index == 3){
                echo $imagepath[2]; // <---and this?
           }
       }
```

Comment: `echo $rs['imagepath'];` ?

Comment: It is name of the column.

Comment: That is the syntax

Comment: `WHERE productid = productid` will select all rows. Why not just leave out the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: take a look at  my update

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = [];

            $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM images
                    WHERE productid = productid"; 

            $select = $db->prepare($sql);
            $select->execute(array());      


        foreach($select as $index => $rs) {
        $rows []= $rs;

       }
                echo $rows[0]['imagepath'];
```

Comment: I want to pick the number of row by myself. That is why I made an if statement. I dont want everything to be outputted. I want only selected ones to be output. And your code is not so usable... :(

Comment: This looks very close to what I want. But your code did not work this time either.

Comment: this code works so either imagepath isn't your column name, or you have a different problem else where

Comment: Can the 'echo' be inside foreach loop? I have it inside the loop. But everything else is the same.

Comment: Depends on how you ordered them.

Answer (score 0):

aren't we missing the fetch function?
`

```
$select = $db->prepare($sql);
$select->execute(array());      

$i = 0;
while($row = $select->fetch()) {
   echo $i . ' '. $row['imagepath'] . '<br>';
   $i++;
}
```

?>
`

--
addendum:
I now understand you only want one, or some, of the images to be shown.
Would it not be easier then, to only select that/those images?

`SELECT imagepath
    FROM images
    WHERE productid = productid
    AND someid = 3`

or if no "someid" is present:

`SELECT imagepath
    FROM images
    WHERE productid = productid
    LIMIT 2,1`

That would avoid the need to loop through may be 100 records to only use the 3th.

Comment: This is good but I want to select the row number by myself. Like  $row['imagepath'][0], $row['imagepath'][1] etc.

Comment: I want to pick the number of row by myself. That is why I made an if statement. I dont want everything to be outputted. I want only selected ones to be output. And your code is not very usable for me.. :(

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a foreach loop is it goes once through each select as "index". so you shouldn't have to worry about making an if-statement for each possible row, just make the statement once, and it will happen on each and every iteration

Comment: I want to pick the number of row by myself. That is why I made an if statement. I dont want everything to be outputted. I want only selected ones to be output. And I can not find it... :(

Comment: you are asking what the right syntax is for $imagepath can you show what $imagepath is?

Comment: It is $rs['imagepath'].